Two strangers meet at a port
Two strangers meet at a port and the man immediately takes liking to the woman. They run into each other couple more times and he convinces her to start a relationship with him. A particular scene of the movie involves with the guy trying to seduce the woman with blindfold and various food items from his fridge. The relationship lasts seven/eight days and the guy has to travel elsewhere. Kindly help me with the name of the movie. It was probably shot around late 80's or early 90's. The actress looked a lot like Michelle Pfeiffer.

Other than the detail of meeting at the port, it sounds like 9½ Weeks (1986), starring Mickey Rourke & Kim Basinger (who I could see being mistaken for Michelle Pfeiffer.)  In particular, you may be thinking of the refrigerator scene between them (which is probably not 100% safe to watch in a public space):




Terrific Michael...that's spot on!!
